# How do i replace attribute text for a particular element in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

So here is how my `custom_1.xml` looks:

```
<customer>
    <name>Customer 1</name>
    <productsPurchased count="2">
        <product>one</product>
        <product>two</product>
    </productsPurchased>
</customer>
```

I want to replace the attribute `count="2"` to have value `4`, so the xml would become:

```
<customer>
    <name>Customer 1</name>
    <productsPurchased count="4">
        <product>one</product>
        <product>two</product>
    </productsPurchased>
</customer>
```

How can I achieve this using `xdmp:node-replace`? I have tried using:

```
xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc("custom_1.xml")/customer/productsPurchased/@count, text { "4" } )
```

But this gives an error: `attribute nodes cannot be replaced with text nodes`

I have also tried replacing the whole element but its too cumbersome and it messes up the namespaces for the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we can use the following to update the attribute text alone:

```
xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc("custom_1.xml")/customer/productsPurchased/@count, attribute { "count" } { "4" } )
```

The `attribute { "count" }` represents the attribute-node with attribute name as "count" just like we have the `text { "some text" }` text node.